# How to calculate daily means, medians, from weather variables data collected hourly in R?

Tags: r

I have this dataframe, "Data", containing one full year of data collected about every half-hour, but for some days only a few hours of data were collected.

Dates are in the format: `31.01.2010 00:30` (all in one cell)
Variables are: `Temperature`, `humidity`, `PM10`, `windspeed`, etc.

**First question**: How can I calculate the daily means, medians, max, min, values of these variables, so I can test each of them in further analysis such as survival analysis with GAM),instead of the hourly/half-hourly data?

Obviously, the calculated daily average/median should be assigned to its corresponding date.

**Second question**: the `DATES` column contains both date and time together, separated by one space in the same cell.
in R, its type is `'Factor'` and I cannot do any calculations, because the error `"dates" is missing`, appears.

My guess is that I need to convert it first from `Factor` into `date/time` so it can be recognized and then to calculate means/medians. But how do I do this?

Can you please indicate what would be the arguments/functions to use?

I think that I have solved the conversion of date from 'Factor' to POSIXlt: I used the function strptime (Data$DATES, format="%d.%m.%Y %H:%M") and now $DATES are recognized as POSIXlt, format "2010-01-01 00:00:00" ....

But I still need to find the function that calculates daily means or averages or medians or whatever.

Comment: I think that I have solved the conversion of date from 'Factor' to POSIXlt: I used the function strptime(Data$DATES, format="%d.%m.%Y %H:%M") and now $DATES are recognized as POSIXlt, format "2010-01-01 00:00:00" ....

Comment: Removed 'survival analysis" and 'gam' tags since neither of them applied to the question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are several parts to the problem. Before calculating the median statistics, you need to massage the dataframe so that it has the appropriate types.

For these explanations I'm going to assume you have a dataframe named `dt`.

**Part 1: Converting the datatypes of the dataframe**

[date factor to datetime StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23094867/how-to-convert-factor-into-datetime-in-r)

[datetime POSIXct conversion StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14658429/2487336)

First you need to convert the `Date` column from the `factor` type to the `datetime` type.

```
dt$Date <- strptime(x = as.character(dt$Date),
                    format = "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M")

dt$date_alt <- as.POSIXct(dt$date_alt) # convert the format of datetime to allow use with ddply
```

Then, since I'm assuming you want the median statistics by `day-month-year`, not including the time, we'll need to extract that info. You'll want to put it in a new column to preserve the times.

```
dt$date_alt <- strptime(x = as.character(dt$Date),
       format = "%d.%m.%Y")
```

**Part 2: Calculating summary statistics grouped by a particular field**

Now that we have the dataframe looking the way we want it, you can calculate the average statistics grouped by the `day-month-year`, which in our case is the `date_alt` column.

The `plyr` package provides a really nice funciton for doing this: `ddply`

```
library(plyr) # need this library for the plyr call

summ <- ddply(dt, .(date_alt), summarize, 
              med_temp = median(!is.na(Temperature)),
              mean_temp = mean(!is.na(Temperature)), # you can also calc mean if you want
              med_humidity = median(!is.na(humidity)),
              med_windspeed = median(!is.na(windspeed))
              # etc for the rest of your vars
          )
```

***Breaking down the `ddply` call:***

[ddply cookbook explanation](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Manipulating_data/Summarizing_data/)

`ddply` is essentially a function which acts over a dataframe. Here's a breakdown of the arguments to the function call:

1. `dt` -- the name of the dataframe you want to iterate over
2. `.(date_alt)` -- the names of the columns you want to group by.
   Conceptually, this splits the dataframe up into a bunch of subdataframes whose rows consist of rows from the original dataframe which share the same values in the columns listed in the parentheses.
3. `summarize` -- this tells the `ddply` call that you want to calculate aggregate statistics on the subdataframes
4. `med_temp = median(Temperature)` and all similar lines -- defines a column in the result data frame. this says that you want the new dataframe to have a column called `med_temp` that contains the `median(Tempurature)` results for each sub-dataframe.
   Keep in mind that instead of `median` you can use whatever function you want for aggregate values.

Comment: Thanks xgord for the valuable information. I have created the alternative column for dates as per your instruction. I will now work on the ddply function, and will post latter, as I need a bit of time to figure out the correct syntax.

Comment: xgord, I have tried your code; seems there is a problem. I got as output after >summ                                                                                                               DATE_ALT med_pm10 mean_pm10 med_temp mean_temp                   1     <NA>        1         1        1         1                                                                 Any ideas of what could be wrong? Thanks.

Comment: I forgot exactly waht it said but something like there is one row only...I can't reproduce the error.

Comment: Sometimes there can be an issue if all of the datetime columns in your dataframe aren't of type `POSIXct`. Make sure when you run `str(dt)` that the posix columns are `POSIXct` and not any other type (ex. `POSIXlt`). Use the `dt$colname <- as.POSIXct(dt$colname)` command with whichever columns aren't the right type.

Comment: I got it Error: length(rows) == 1 is not TRUE

Comment: Yes, the dates are recognized as POSIXlt, not as POSIXct as you reccomend. I will try again and post latter. Thanks.

Comment: another thing to check: make sure inside the `ddply` call you're using `summarize` and ***not*** `summary` -- there's a difference between those 2 functions

Comment: Well, I changed both the DATE and the DATE_ALT as POSIXct, and tried again. The same error came: Error: length(rows) == 1 is not TRUE. Does it mean that the DATE_ALT column contains only one row? just my wild guessing, lol. I have no idea what it may signify

Comment: see previous comment about `summarize` vs `summary`. also what does your `ddply` call look like?

Comment: Yes I saw it. I am using the summarize function. As for the ddply, it seems to be working. One detail, It warned when I loaded the plyr package, saying that I should have loaded first cause ddply was already loaded. Does it make sense? Maybe I should start again from fresh R session?

Comment: Where / during which commands is the error being thrown? Also can you put your ddply call here?

Comment: xgord, sorry for the delay. I figured out where the problem was: One problem was the code: dt$date_alt <- strptime(x = as.character(dt$Date),
       format = "%d.%m.%Y")  This was wrong. It had to be as.Date. I corrected it with this code: dt$date_alt <- as.Date(dt$Date, format="%d.%m.%Y"). Then, the other problem was in the ddply code you proposed; for example, instead of writing the code: med_temp=median(!is.na(Temperature)), I wrote this code as: median=median(Temp), and the same for the others. So after >summ I get the matrix with dates listed by days and the columns of means and medians.

Answer (score 0):

First, convert your time series into a `xts` object.
Then compute the data you want using `xts` functions such as `apply.daily()`
See, the `xts` vignette [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xts/vignettes/xts.pdf).

I feel that the following snippet should work:

```
# Load library xts
require(xts)

# Create example dataframe 
datetime <- c('31.01.2010 00:30', '31.01.2010 00:31', '31.01.2010 10:32', '01.02.2010 10:00', '01.02.2010 11:03', '01.03.2011 08:09', '01.03.2011 21:00', '01.03.2011 22:00')
value <- c(1.5, 2, 2.5, 7, 3.5, 9, 4.5, 7.5)
df <- data.frame(datetime, value)

# Create xts object
df.xts <- as.xts(df[,2], order.by=as.Date(df[,1], format='%d.%m.%Y %H:%M'))

# Daily mean
d.mean <- apply.daily(df.xts, mean)

# Daily median
d.median <- apply.daily(df.xts, median)

# Daily min
d.min <- apply.daily(df.xts, min)

# Daily max
d.max <- apply.daily(df.xts, max)
```

(alternatively, see [RFiddle](http://www.r-fiddle.org/#/fiddle?id=KnLg3PRG))

Comment: edouard, I checked the xts vignette, and found nothing about median, means, or other common statistics; are you sure this package can do that? Anyways, the option below, proposed by xgord works, though.

Comment: hello, i edited my answer just now. please see above. (hopefully i got what you were after)